# How can I handle dynamic obstacle in voxel navigation system (on 3D Game Server)

Tags: navigation, path-finding, voxel

I'm making a voxel based navigation system that will be applied to a 3D game server.

I'm using the A * algorithm, and of course I have no problem getting the path for terrain information that doesn't change.

But when the dynamic obstacles are included, the story is different.

I adopted a way to sample dynamic obstacles into voxels and update the terrain information corresponding to those voxels as 'obstacles'.

However, updating the terrain by resampling each time a dynamic obstacle moves requires too much resources.

In addition, this type of processing is more dangerous if concurrent access is concentrated in one sector.

Are there any more efficient ideas I can use?

Comment: Generally in games you optimize pathfinding by (1) Only re-running the pathfinding at infrequent intervals; (2) sharing results among multiple units (if applicable); and (3) using approximation algorithms like HPA\* or Anytime A\*

Comment: Thanks for letting me know a good optimization.

But my question is how can we treat terrain that is not a wall as a 'wall' caused by dynamic obstacles?

The simplest method I used was to sample a dynamic obstacle into a voxel and change the value of the corresponding voxel data to 'wall'.

However, as mentioned in this article, this task requires a lot of resources. Because of this, I'm looking for a way for the algorithm to treat the area occupied by the obstacle as a 'wall' without having to sample the dynamic obstacle as a voxel.

Comment: First of all, I solved this problem by supporting only certain types of agents.

For example, it only supports cubes, spheres, and cylinders of a certain size as shapes that the agent can have.

In this way, we don't have to 'sample' the mesh every time, and we expect to reduce the load because we only need to change the voxel data each time the agent moves / rotates. But still, I want to support agents with arbitrary shapes. Therefore, the problem is not completely solved.